# Adding new column comparing with another column

Tags: r

For example, I have a data frame. I want to add another column into that data frame.

The condition is if Sepal.Length >=5, 10, 15  assign "short" "medium" "long" . Could you please show me the command?

Comment: Can you include a reproducible example along with expected output ?

Comment: To add reproducible example use `dput`. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work using dplyr (assuming you're using the iris data set):

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

iris2 <- iris %>% 
  mutate(length = case_when(
    Sepal.Length < 5 ~ "short", 
    Sepal.Length < 7 ~ "medium",
    TRUE ~ "long" # This catches all other cases
    )
  )
```

You'll have to adjust the code a little for your specific situation. Note also that data quality issues may break this solution if there's a case I haven't accounted for.